# grunt htmlmin not sending to dist folder

Tags: gruntjs

I have set up my grunt to minify my html, but when I run 'grunt htmlmin'
it doesnt send it to my dist folder, here are the settings I used:

```
htmlmin: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'src',
            src: '**/*.html',
            dest: 'dist/'
        }],
        },
    },
```

Do I have something set up wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems fine - below is the exact `Gruntfile.js` that works on my machine. Can you try it on your side?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    removeComments: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'src',
                    src: '**/*.html',
                    dest: 'dist/'
                }],
            },
        },
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-htmlmin');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['htmlmin']);
};
```

Comment: It is saying
                                                                                                                                                 
    minified 0 files

when I have a index.html
Do I need to have more than 1 html file for it to work?

Comment: Minify works fine with only 1 file, must be something else. In what folder is your index.html located?